# Accrued Interest on Corporate Bonds

Tags: united-states, income-tax, bonds

A hypothetical investor buy a corporate bond on Dec 5, 2020 and pays $1000 dollars of accrued interest. The bond then pays him $1500 dollars of interest on March 1, 2021. I claim that $1000 dollars of accrued interest is deductible on his 2021 income tax return. It is not deductible on his 2020 income tax return. This is true even if he does not itemize. The reason for this is that $1000 of the $1500 he got in March was his own money. Do I have this right?

The investor lives in the United States.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not exactly. In 2021 you would claim $500 of interest income, not a $1,000 deduction in 2020 and $1,500 income in 2021. The accrued interest you pay is not really an "expense" since you get it back at the next coupon payment (or when you sell the bond, whichever comes first).

This is included in the [instructions for Schedule B](https://www.irs.gov/instructions/i1040sb):

> **Accrued interest.**
>
> When you buy bonds between interest payment dates and pay accrued
> interest to the seller, this interest is taxable to the seller. If you
> received a Form 1099 for interest as a purchaser of a bond with
> accrued interest, follow the rules earlier under Nominees to see how
> to report the accrued interest. But identify the amount to be
> subtracted as "Accrued Interest."

Comment: @D Stanley So you are saying you reduce the bond interest you receive in 2021 not 2020 even if you have other bonds that pay taxable interest to you. Do I have that right?

Comment: @Bob That's how I read it.  Investment interest expense is interest that you pay when you _borrow_ money to invest. That's not what paying accrued interest is. It's just part of the purchase of the bond.